# How can i create a navigation panel in extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs5

How can i create a navigation panel like the attached screenshot.

I checked in the sencha kitchen sink, there is no ext component that suits this. Is there a plugin available? if not how can this be done ?

[image: panel is collapsed]

[image: panel is opened]

Comment: I am not concerned about the color / style here. I want to know how a ext component (like panel) can be used to build this .

Comment: Take a look at the Executive Dashboard and the Responsive Design demo's in the Combination Examples area http://dev.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/examples/index.html

Comment: Where you get that capture image from ?
can you tell me about that, or you have a link ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this existed when you originally posted this question; however, a side navigation like this can be accomplished using a tree list using the property micro and some styling.

[Modern Framework Example](http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/examples/kitchensink/?modern#tree-list)

[Classic Framework Example](http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/examples/kitchensink/?classic#tree-list)

Someone in the comments asked, where they captured the image from. It's from the [Angle template](http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB04HF123).